# Levels of an object's luminosity

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

Is there a concise list somewhere of terms used to describe a range of "brightness" or "luminosity"? Say from dim to blinding as an example. I tried Googling it and searching Wikipedia, but all I got were thesaurus and mathematical definitions.

The closest I've found is the luminosity charts for stars, but unfortunately they don't have word designations for each range.

Comment: The degree of light is described by its level of [*illumination*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/illumination), or "the luminous flux per unit area on an intercepting surface at any given point." Units of measure are, variously, *lux*, *lumen*, *phot*, and *foot candle*. What *range* is associated with what *adjective* is completely subjective. Even if there were lists somewhere, they would be arbitrary and far from authoritative. (What is considered *blinding* to someone may not be considered *blinding* to someone else. And different contexts will determine different adjectives.)

Comment: It might be wirth having a look at [light reflectance values] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_reflectance_value), but I'm afraid no words here.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me illustrate how hard this is:

I started by searching for adjectives describing light in the Oxford Historical Thesaurus. It is a powerful tool that categorizes words by functions and lists their synonyms. Because *lightness* and *darkness* are often treated as separate qualities, the words are listed under two different headers:

> the world > matter > light > intensity of light >  [adjective] (91)
>
> the world > matter > light > darkness or absence of light > dimness or absence of brightness >  [adjective] (65)

Word lists will tend towards the same flaw. This [list](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/36-adjectives-describing-light/)? Or [this one](https://positivethesaurus.com/words-to-describe-light/)? It's mostly words describing light. It's hard to organize these into strict ranges, since there will be a lot of overlap between entries. (You try describing the difference between "sparkling" and "coruscating.")

This [list from RhymeZone](https://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?Word=brightness&typeofrhyme=jjb&loc=morejja) is better, since the second half of the entries cover levels of brightness as well as dimness. It isn't in order of brightness, but it's a start.

Comment: Something else to add to my list of unhelpful/inaccurate lists!